# Why does boiler flue have to be sealed on both sides?

Tags: boiler, flue

My boiler flue isn't sealed on the inside. Only the outside.

I read it needs to be sealed on both sides.  But why does it need to be sealed on the inside?  Since its unsealed at the moment I can see from the hole whether the outside is sealed on the other end.

If it is in case a leak happens on the inner side, I guess that means you should not also seal any crack in the kitchen because the leak would travel in the wall and out through any crack so why not say that.

Or is it to be sealed for a different reason?

Thanks.

Comment: it is totally unclear what you are talking about ... not everyone has what you have ... and nobody can see what you are looking at

Comment: Are you talking about a brick chimney for the flue or multi wall pipe?